# Shared variable is executing after subreport Crystal Reports

Tags: variables, crystal-reports, report, shared, subreport

I'm using Crystal Reports 14. I have a master report containing only details section, filled from 3 sub reports. The detail section is a single page per record, filtered by Employee ID. That means that when the Employee ID 100 is displayed on the master report, the other 3 sub reports show details from the Employee with ID 100. I have a shared variable, that sum's an amount from a sub report, and it is displayed on a different area on Master report detail section.

this is the code on Master report

```
Shared NumberVar x;
```

And this is the code on Subreport

```
Shared NumberVar x:= (Sum ({Command.amount}));
```

The problem is that when i display Employee ID 100 the first value is 0. On the next page 
i get the value of the previous employee ID and so on.

If my assumption is correct, this may have to do with sub report value is executing after Master report. Having only details section and page per record this is a bummer

Any ideas?

Comment: are you placing the shared variable after the subreport on your main report(different section)?

Comment: No, in the same. I explained that i have only details section. No, header, no group, no footer.

Comment: but you can add another details section an place it there, for example detailsA with subreport, detailsB with subreport, detailsC with subreport and detailsD with shared variable

Comment: The main report section is on the left and the sub report on the right. How i can separate them vertically? I'm thinking that this is not a possibility and maybe if there is no other way, then change the layout, unfortunately. But i would like to avoid plan b

Comment: put the subreport over the main report and go the details section and check underlay section below

Comment: Thanks for your help. I guess that would do. I will make some adjustments to the layout but that's not a problem. I with i could give you reputation points :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place shared variable in a different section than your subreport is. Put your sureport in a section above your main report is and go to details section expert and check underlay section below.